# Magento 2 custom cron job is not getting scheduled

Tags: magento2

I am adding custom Cron job but it is not getting scheduled even after I run:`php bin/magento cron:run`.
and I have also tried with Cron custom groups and ran by command still not getting generated in cron_schedule table, Please help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crontab.xml` in `etc` folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\Cron" method="execute" name="vendor_module_cronjob">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Under `Cron/Cron.php` :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;

class Cron
{

    public function execute()
    {

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/cron.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info(__METHOD__);

        return $this;

    }
}

?>
```

It should works. In command line run `php bin/magento cron:run --group="default"`

Comment: thanks bro..it helped me

Comment: glad to help :D , please mark my answer as a correct answer

Comment: can you please help me in this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301972/how-can-i-hide-extra-sliding-images-from-product-detail-page

Comment: I've answered, you can check if this was an issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try this reference module from [Github](https://github.com/vrajeshkpatel/module-sample-cron)

Comment: can you please help me in this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301972/how-can-i-hide-extra-sliding-images-from-product-detail-page