# How can I hide extra sliding images from product detail page?

Tags: magento2

I have attached the screenshot below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf3tV.png

As you can see there is a black and white color image, but I want to when I select black the white images in small slider should not display.

Please help in this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you creat configuration at `Step 3: Bulk Images, Price and Quantity` you can choose `Apply unique images by attribute to each SKU` and then you aplly images to each configuration. Then on product page when you choose for example color black , only images from color black are shown.

Comment: Probably you added all images on main page of adding product. In ```Images and Videos``` tab